# Visual Studio Code not responding

Tags: visual-studio-code

For the last two days, I am facing a problem with my VSCode. Whenever I write any C/C++ code and click on run, there is no response shown by VSCode. I even uninstalled the whole setup and installed it again but the same issue I am facing again. What should I do to resolve it?

Comment: Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code (VSCode) are two different products. Which one are you using?

Comment: In any case, if it stops responding _only_ when you run specific code, then you should [edit] the question and include that code there.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio code and it is not responding for any of the C/C++ program .Their is no change in the terminal.